# GET method gets empty result before reloading app(on production) - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I wrote an API for a mobile app. The flow of app is, after registering user, get the products list. Registering method:

```
def create
  user =  #assign some params
  if user.save
    #some codes here
  end
end
```

the get list products method:

```
def full_list
  ...
  products = Product.by_user_and_list_name(current_user: current_user, list_name: "products", check_for_new_version: check_for_new_version).take(PER_PAGE).to_a
  ...
end
```

the two methods are called respectively. Now I got a problem is the `full_list` always returns empty at the first time(reload app then the list will show), this only happens on the production, in staging and local, it works properly. I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that current_user is set before you call full_list?

Comment: @DarrenInksetter yes, it was set because it worked well in local and staging